# mongodb/mongoose: Save unique value if data is not null in from nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to save data in MongoDB. I want to store unique data when data is not null. However, I want to allow multiple null values in the unique identifier.

My sample schema:

```
@Schema()
export class Contact extends Document {
  @Prop({ unique: true, sparse: true, require: true })
  email: string;
  
  @Prop({ default: '+1' })
  countryCode: string;

  @Prop({ unique: true, sparse: true })
  mobile: string;
}
```

In this case, a mobile number is not required. User can add their contact information with or without providing a mobile number. If the user sends their mobile number that should be unique. So, I need to allow multiple `null` values in the `mobile` field. However, that field should be unique when the user provides any mobile number.

Empty entries seem to get the value `null` so every entry without `mobile` crashes with the `unique` identifier.

Is there any way to solve this problem either from the database layer or the application layer?

I am using NestJS for developing my API.

Comment: Check nestjs validation: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Answer (score 2):

A unique index still does not allow multiple docs with a field of null. You need to transform your data payload by dropping the null field before you save your docs in MongoDB. A transform pipe will help you to handle this issue. Here is a transform pipe that you can use for this purpose:

```
@Injectable()
export class NullValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private isObj(obj: any): boolean {
    return typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null;
  }

  private dropNull(values) {
    Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
      if (!(key === 'password' || key === '_id')) {
        if (this.isObj(values[key])) {
          values[key] = this.dropNull(values[key]);
        } else if (Array.isArray(values[key]) && values[key].length > 0) {
          values[key] = values[key].map((value) => {
            if (this.isObj(value)) {
              value = this.dropNull(value);
            }
            return value;
          });
        } else {
          if (values[key] === null || values[key] === undefined) {
            delete values[key];
          }
        }
      }
    });
    return values;
  }

  transform(values: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { type } = metadata;
    if (type === 'param' || type === 'custom') return values;
    else if (this.isObj(values) && type === 'body') {
      return this.dropNull(values);
    }

    throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
  }
}
```

Use this pipe in the controller and this pipe will drop all incoming null fields which will come with the request payload.

You can also check nest pipe transform docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation